# How to get the ID of a Form in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to get the id of a form so that i can save the form `id` to the database so that i can create dynamic record:
for example, i am trying to create a signatories of a form(e.g. Approved by:,Requested By:), But the result is zero.

Heres my code for VB.NET

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim form_id As Integer = Me.AccessibleDescription
        MsgBox(form_id)
    End Sub
```

Heres my code for c#:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int form_id = this.AccessibleDescription;
    Interaction.MsgBox(form_id);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you think `AccessibleDescription` is?

Comment: I'm surprised that compiles. AccessibleDescription appears to be a string (according to docs).

Comment: for what i am understanding, it is the name or a id of a control.
so what is the way to get the id of a form?

Comment: for example: i have 5 forms, how can i get the ID's of those forms?

Comment: What is the *ID of a Form*?

Comment: any ID(integer) as long as i can dynamically create records to it.
for example in the form1 the id is 1 then the form2 is 2 and so on...
why i'm doing this is that i will store all the signatories of a form like(Requested by:, Approved By:)

Comment: Wht not you should use some kind of GUID's for each form?

Comment: @ErdzWardex, check out an answer I have just posted. You can use either of the 2 approaches to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of ways of dealing with your scenario. In both ways, *you need to set the corresponding property of the form in Design view*, so its permanently saved.

1. Just use the Name property of form, but just make sure that you set this property to a unique string for each form in your application. If you wanted to store only integers for each form identifier then parse the Name property for the integer at end of the Name; for example, if `Me.Name = "Form1"` then parse Form1 to get `1` as the form identifier.

   ```
   ''put this line in Form Load event
   Dim formIdentifier as string = Me.Name


   ''OR use the integer part as identifier in form name assuming
   ''you name each form starting with Form
   ''and then an integer
   Dim formIdentifier as string = Me.Name.Substring(4)
   ```
2. The second option is to set the value of `Tag` property of the form and use that as the identifier. This property allows developers to attach any custom string value to a form. For example, in screen shot below I have assigned `formFinance` as the tag which I can use as the identifier of form. Make sure Tag property has a unique value for each form.

   ```
   ''put this line in Form Load event
   Dim formIdentifier as string = Me.Tag
   ```

[image: Set Tag value for a Form]

Comment: Ohh thank you for this answer, i just remember that you can set a value to a tag of a form!

Answer (score 0):

O.K so here is asolution from code project:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/853501/How-I-Can-Get-List-Of-All-Forms-In-My-Project-Usin
which you change to your needs.

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim types As Type() = myAssembly.GetTypes()
    For Each t As Type In types
        If UCase(t.BaseType.ToString) = "SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.FORM" Then
            'MessageBox.Show(t.Name)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(t.Name)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```